# How do I create a speech to text recognition with a type writer effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js

I'm trying to create a type writing effect over my speech recognition w/ P5 so it will type out each word or character at a time instead of the whole sentence at once.

Comment: What did you tried? Pls show some code!

Comment: var myRec = new p5.SpeechRec(); // new P5.SpeechRec object



  // SPEECH STUFF
 function setup()
 {
  // graphics stuff:
  createCanvas(800, 100);
  background(255,255, 255);
  fill(0, 0, 0, 255);
  // instructions:
  textSize(32);
  textAlign(RIGHT);
  text("so tell me about yourself...?", width/2, height/2);
  myRec.onResult = showResult;
  myRec.start();
 }

 function showResult()
 {
  if(myRec.resultValue==true) {
   background(255, 255, 255);
   text(myRec.resultString, width/2, height/2);
   console.log(myRec.resultString);

  }
 }

Comment: For javascript, you can you setTimeout like [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp).
Anw, you should place your code with a better format in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the javascript [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function:

```
let sound;

let resultString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"

let str = "";
let index = 0;

function preload() {
  sound = loadSound("path to your sound file");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    str += resultString[index];
    sound.play();
    index++;

    if (str == resultString)
      clearInterval(interval);
  }, 800);

  textAlign(CENTER, BOTTOM);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  text(str, width / 2, height / 2);
}
```